# Reuse css properties from jquery-ui framework classes?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, sass, less

jQueryUI provides a convenient css framework: http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/API

Just by using jQueryUI's CSS classes (ui-widget-content, ui-widget-header, etc), you can easily create html-snippets that are themeable via http://jqueryui.com/ThemeRoller

A feature what I'm sometimes missing in designing my apps, is to reuse a css property from jquery-UI's CSS classes, but not all of the properties. Simple reuse is possible by using `none !important`.

For example, when you only want to get the foreground `color` of `.ui-widget-content` without backgrounds or borders, you could just do:

```
<style>
.no-background { background: none !important; }
.no-border { border: none !important; }
</style>
<div class="ui-widget-content no-background no-border">
  hi world :)
</div>
```

But, is there a simple way to get the `background-color` of `.ui-widget-header` and reuse it in my own CSS classes as `color` ?

I made a somewhat quick and dirty solution for this: filling a style tag using JavaScript and DOM manipulation.

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/ijuxar/7/edit

HTML Code:

```
<style class="computedStyles"></style>
<div class="cssHelper ui-helper-hidden-accessible" style="visibility: hidden">
  <div class="ui-widget-header"></div>
  <div class="ui-widget-content"></div>
  <div class="ui-state-default"></div>
  <div class="ui-widget-header ui-state-active"></div>
  <div class="ui-widget-header ui-state-hover"></div>
</div>
<h1 class="ui-color-2">Hi World</h1>
```

JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var css= '', i, colors = [
      $('.cssHelper .ui-widget-content').css('color'),
      $('.cssHelper .ui-widget-header').css('background-color'),
      $('.cssHelper .ui-state-hover').css('background-color'),
      $('.cssHelper .ui-state-default').css('background-color'),
      $('.cssHelper .ui-widget-header.ui-state-active').css('background-color')
  ];
  for (i = 0; i < colors.length; i += 1) {
      css += '.ui-color-' + (i + 1) + ' { color: ' + colors[i] + '}\n';
  }
  $('style.computedStyles:first').text(css);
});
```

I feel that the JavaScript solution is somewhat evil. Furthermore, it causes a [FOUC](http://www.bluerobot.com/web/css/fouc.asp/) in some browsers.

Is it possible to get it done with plain CSS and/or with serverside tools (SASS/LESS/...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheets.  which means styles set by classes will "cascade"

So if you have your own css file, and include it AFTER the jquery css.  It will over ride the jquery css.  Likewise, if you attach 2 classes to an html element,  the 2nd classes styles will over-write the first ones.

the other way to over write specific styles of a css class, is to use the !important indicator on your css. something marked !important will not be over written by something that isn't  no matter what order they appear in.

So to answer your question.   In your own css file,  have your class that specifies the color like so:

```
.myColour{
    background-:none!important;
    border:none!important;
}
```

and class your element like so:

```
<div class="ui-widget-content myColour" >
  hi world :)
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, the `!important` indicator is a great way to create ThemeRoller-compatible css classes. But I haven't found a clean way to reuse, for example: the `background-color` of `ui-widget-header`  as a `border-color`

Comment: ooooh, i misunderstood your question.  you want to use values from different style properties for other style properties?

Comment: yep, the boss who watches my screen allways adds strange demands to my todo-list ;) guess this is only possible with some server-side CSS pre-processor?

Comment: hmm, yea, i don't really know a good way to do that :(  sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged you question with less as well, I suppose you can use it. There would be a solution for you, perhaps not perfect but imo cleaner then what you are using now.

You probably know that you can use a class name A inside your style declaration B to apply all the style properties from A to class B. It is called a Mixin: http://lesscss.org/#-mixins

I guess you could achieve what you are after by first using a mixin and later overwriting its properies. Your syntax would look something like this:

**master.less:**

```
@import "jquery-ui.less"

 ... 

.myCustomWidget {
  .ui-widget-content;
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

...
```

Note that i changed the extension of the jquery-ui.css to .less to make the less compiler actualy include the file, rather then leaving the @import statement as is. Since css is also valid less that should be all you need to do to it.

If you then compile your less to css you get a single class .myCustomWidget you can use apply in your HTML, without the need for additional classes. Also, if you change the jquery-ui.css by applying a different theme or something, you would only have to recompile your master.less to incorporate the changes. (I would strongly advise you to precompile your less files locally or server-side, rather then having it be done by js on the client side. This to prevent making your styles js dependant)

Also note that you will no longer need to link to the actual jquery-ui.css file in your html, as it will be entirelyt included in the compiled master.css file. This means one less page request, wich should give you a performance bonus.

Comment: I already had a look at mixins, but I was asking if there is a way to reuse, for example: the `background-color` of `ui-widget-header` as a `border-color` ?

Comment: It appears there is a less out there to build jqueryUi themes. http://jqueryuilesscss.sourceforge.net/ I did not yet investigate it further, but i suppose the colors will be variables and you should be able to reuse thes variables in your own less files if you import them. Think this is worth investigating...